# How can I access an array index in ASyncTask for my UI Updating?

Tags: android, arrays, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have an ASyncTask which is running the update for my UserInterface; but I am not sure how I can access my AnalogInput[] parameter and check which index I am currently on for when I call my publishProgress();

```
private class AnalogUpdater extends AsyncTask<AnalogInput[], Float, Void> {

    // A callback method executed on non UI thread, invoked after
    // onPreExecute method if exists

    // Takes a set of parameters of the type defined in your class
    // implementation. This method will be
    // executed on the background thread, so it must not attempt to interact
    // with UI objects.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(AnalogInput[]... params) {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                publishProgress(params[0][i].getVoltage());
            }

        } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... f) {
        // Getting reference to the TextView tv_counter of the layout
        // activity_main
        final String str = String.format("Voltage: %.2f", f);
        final int v = Math.round(f[0] * 100);
        switch (idx // How can I get this index?) {
        case 1:
            analogInput0VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput0VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 2:
            analogInput1VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput1VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 3:
            analogInput2VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput2VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 4:
            analogInput3VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput3VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 5:
            analogInput4VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput4VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 6:
            analogInput5VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput5VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 7:
            analogInput6VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput6VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 8:
            analogInput7VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput7VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 9:
            analogInput8VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput8VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 10:
            analogInput9VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput9VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 11:
            analogInput10VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput10VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 12:
            analogInput11VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput11VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 13:
            analogInput12VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput12VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 14:
            analogInput13VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput13VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 15:
            analogInput14VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput14VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        case 16:
            analogInput15VoltageText.setText(str);
            analogInput15VoltageBar.setProgress(v);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Hopefully this is clear; refer to the comment "How can I get this index?" in the code.
    }

Comment: well, you could create a small object to hold both the voltage and the  index, then pass both together in the same object, as opposed to passing just a float.

Comment: So like a new Java object class with the constructors of index and voltage; then just change the AsyncTask Progress to the type of the new object?

Comment: yes.  That is what I would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array as the second parameter on your asyncTask (might not be necessary, I don't really remember)

```
private class AnalogUpdater extends AsyncTask<AnalogInput[], Float[], Void>
```

Pass both values, voltage and index (cast index to float)

```
publishProgress(params[0][i].getVoltage(), (float)i);
```

And use it later (cast to int again)

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... f)
{
    idx = (int)f[1];
}
```

Comment: That would be easier, and that was my first thought, but I'd be worried about round off errors.  I guess you could always add .5 before casting.

Comment: @SteveSchwarcz Casting an `int` to a `float` and then backwards should be safe (casting a `float` to `int` and then backwards would definitely not work well).

Comment: I ended up approaching the object method that Steve had recommended; but I am going to post a followup question on a related issue.